# Program to view active network adapters

Tags: windows, networking, mac, adapter

Could anyone offer any windows program that could detect network adapters that are active and view their MAC addresses?
Already tried MACAddressView, but that one shows all adapter's physical addresses, and i only need the active ones.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

#### How do I get the MAC addresses of active network adapters?

You can use the following PowerShell command:

> ```
> (Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration -ComputerName $env:COMPUTERNAME | Where{$_.IpEnabled -Match "True"} | Select-Object -Expand macaddress) -join ","
> ```

Source [Get only ethernet MAC-address via command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29201132/get-only-ethernet-mac-address-via-command-prompt) answer by unknown user.